# Get Foreign keys in the table

Tags: c#, mysql

I created one script to display the foreign keys in the particular table.

```
SELECT  i.CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i
LEFT JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE k ON
i.CONSTRAINT_NAME = k.CONSTRAINT_NAME WHERE i.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
AND i.TABLE_NAME = 'sample';
```

When I execute this command in my host, it displays the list of foreign key constraints found in all the databases with `table` name `"sample"`.

But i need particular database, sample table `foreign keys`.

Comment: Please any one solve my problem

Comment: I got query:SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'tablename';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add at the end

```
AND i.table_schema = '<the name of your database which is a schema>'
```

EDIT :

Change the left join to

```
LEFT JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
   ON i.CONSTRAINT_NAME = k.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND 
      i.TABLE_SCHEMA = k.TABLE_SCHEMA
```

because you could find constraint with same name in different schemas.

[what's a schema and a database in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/schemata-table.html)

Comment: I'm having 3 database. all are having the sample table. I added this constraint in my query like this:SELECT i.TABLE_NAME, i.CONSTRAINT_TYPE, i.CONSTRAINT_NAME, k.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, k.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i
LEFT JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE k ON i.CONSTRAINT_NAME = k.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE i.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
AND i.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database1'
AND i.TABLE_NAME = 'sample';

Comment: Single sample table having 3 keys. The result of the above query is 9 foreign keys. That's it displayed all keys in the 3 database

Answer (score 0):

Need to select the database before run this query. Following may be helpful.

```
USE YourDatabaseName

SELECT  i.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i
LEFT JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE k
ON i.CONSTRAINT_NAME = k.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE i.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
AND i.TABLE_NAME = 'sample'
```